# Find and copy files to directorywith getopts

Tags: bash

I have a bash script that I need to pass in the files to be copied (`*.cpp`) and the directory to copy to (`cfiles/backup`).  The problem is it only copies the first file instead of all the files in the directory.

```
#!/bin/bash

while getopts "ab:" input; do
case $input in
    a)
        #an option
        ;;
    b)
        # Get the wild card and destination passed in
        # wildcard=$OPTARG 
        dest="${@: -1}"
        #Make the directory if it doesn't exit
        mkdir -p $dest 2>1
        find . -name "$OPTARG" -type f -exec cp {} $dest \; 2>1
        printf 'string = %b| destination = %b\n' $OPTARG $dest
        ;;
    ?)
        echo "Error! Invalid option provided" >&2
        exit 1
        ;;
    :) 
        echo "Option -$OPTARG missing parameter!" >&2
        ;;

esac
done
```

The problem is it only ever copies 1 file any insight will be appreciated!

Comment: 2>1 could be 2>$1

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a -r at the end of your cp command. This performs a recursive file copy on the directory.

```
find . -name "$OPTARG" -type f -exec cp -r {} $dest \; 2>1
```

Comment: Awesome thanks! thought it would be something simple I had missed

Comment: still only seems to be copying 1 file instead of doing it recursively